# chmod +x not working in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, chmod

I am having issues getting cygwin to accept the chmod command:

```
JonP@price8560p /cygdrive/c/C2dev/Git/c2/bin/ffmpeg
$ chmod -v +x ffmpeg
mode of `ffmpeg' changed from 0644 (rw-r--r--) to 0755 (rwxr-xr-x)

JonP@price8560p /cygdrive/c/C2dev/Git/c2/bin/ffmpeg
$ ls -l
total 33384
-rw-r--r-- 1 JonP Domain Users 17124156 Jun 20 16:57 ffmpeg
-rw-r--r-- 1 JonP Domain Users 17056860 Jun 20 16:57 ffprobe
```

Anyone have any ideas why after the change above the file still shows as not executable?

Per comments below:

```
$ df -T /cygdrive/c
Filesystem     Type 1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
C:             ntfs 467159036 162434212 304724824  35% /cygdrive/c
```

Comment: What does `df -T /cygdrive/c` tell you?

Comment: This is discussed in the Cygwin FAQ: http://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.chmod  FAT32 filesystems don't have an attribute for +x

Comment: Sorry, I should have noted that I already checked and it is NTFS and not FAT32.

    `$ df -T /cygdrive/c
    Filesystem     Type 1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
    C:             ntfs 467159036 162434212 304724824  35% /cygdrive/c`

Comment: Cygwin does some magic with files with the `.exe` suffix -- and I'd expect that file to be named `ffmpeg.exe` (but it can also be accessed as `ffmpeg` for Unix compatibility). What happens if you try `mv ffmpeg ffmpeg.exe ; chmod +x ffmpeg.exe`?

Comment: I will give that a shot.  Problem is, this is getting tar-ed up and moved to a unix machine, s oi will add the extension chmod it, and then remove and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

try chmod -v 0577 ffmpeg. if it doesn't work, use full path of ffmpeg

Comment: Nope, sorry, sadly this doesn't work for me.